# Saving variable after event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Could someone explain me please why this didn't working:
http://jsfiddle.net/4nzYr/

```
<ul>
    <li class="draggable">hello</li>
    <li class="draggable">how are you today</li>
</ul>
```

and..

```
  $(function(){
        $('.draggable').draggable({axis: 'y', start: function (event, ui){var dragged=true}})
            if (dragged == true){$('<p>super</p>').appendTo($('.draggable'))}
            })
```

I i expected append new paragraph. And for more i expected to have possibility to use variable dragged to other actions.

Comment: Please post your code in the question, and also explain what you expect it to do and what actually happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling this code only once when the page loads.  This will never be append because the code is never run again after dragging.

```
if (dragged == true){
    $('<p>super</p>').appendTo('li');
}
```

You need another event to stick this code block into.  Also notice that dragged is now defined outside of draggable's start delegate.  For example:

```
$(function() {
    var dragged = false;

    $('.draggable').draggable({
        axis: 'y',
        start: function (event, ui) {
            dragged = true;
        }
    });

    $('#checkButton').click(function() {
        if (dragged == true){
            $('<p>super</p>').appendTo('li');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So it saves me variable for now and for the past but don't activate `appendTo` because the only event which activate this metohd is  $(document).ready(), and  $(document).ready() happends before drag event, right?

Comment: ready event fires once - when the page (actually the DOM) loads.  how can a user drag something on the page before the page loads?  makes sense?

Comment: Read up some more on ready - http://api.jquery.com/ready/.  And in general, you can always get more info on api.jquery.com